# PostgreSQL exclusive or on column setting

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

In PostgreSQL 9.5 I'm wanting to create a table with three columns.  I'd basically have something like

```sql
create table Foo (
   account varchar not null,
   team_id integer references team (ident) on delete cascade,
   league_id integer references league (ident) on delete cascade
)
```

The fun part now is that I want them to specify EITHER `team_id` OR `league_id`, but not both.  The combination of `account` plus one of the other two columns is then the UNIQUE constraint.

Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure only one of the columns is supplied, use a check constraint:

```
alter table foo add 
   constraint check_team check (not (team_id is not null and league_id is not null));
```

The above will however not prevent providing a NULL value for **both** columns. If you want to make sure that **exactly** one of them is provided you can use:

```
alter table foo add 
   constraint check_team check ( (team_id is not null or league_id is not null) 
                                 and not (team_id is not null and league_id is not null));
```

Edit: as Abelisto pointed out, the check constraint can be simplified to

```
alter table foo add 
   constraint check_team check ((team_id is null) <> (league_id is null));
```

I'm not sure about the unique constraint you want to establish. If e.g. the following two rows should be prevented `('x', 1, null)`, `('x', null, 1)` then you can use a unique index like this:

```
create unique index on foo (account, coalesce(team_id, league_id));
```

That would only work properly if you enforce the rule that at least one of those columns must be not null.

If however you want to allow the same team in different columns, but want to prevent to have he same team_id or league_id twice for an account (allowing the above example) then I think you need to unique indexes:

```
create unique index on foo (account, team_id) where team_id is not null; 
create unique index on foo (account, league_id) where league_id is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your second example was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Actually, this only answers part of the question.  Now I've ensured they provide either a team or a league, but not both.  How do I now add the UNIQUE constraint so it's the pair that are checked?  To your question, `('x', 1, null)` and `('x', null, 1)` would both be OK as they're distinct from each other.

Comment: Scratch that.  The unique constraint ends up just being all three together :)

Comment: `... check ((team_id is null) <> (league_id is null));`

Comment: @Abelisto: ah, good. I was wondering if the check constraint can be simplified.